# General Tree stops adding Nodes in java

Tags: java, recursion, tree

My implementation of a general family tree stops adding nodes to the tree after the ninth node in my input file is added.

Inputs look like this:

```
[0] ,111
[1] 111,113
[2] 111,112
[3] 112,PstDC3000
[4] 112,Pae1
[5] 113,219
[6] 113,114 
[7] 114,116
[8] 114,115
[9] 115,GLGR
[10] 115,Baq35567
[11] 116,117
...
[219] 219,VchN16961
```

Next are the code fragments that relate to the building of this tree in Java:

In main the code builds a tree with the input scanned in from the text file:

```
while(scn.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[] lineData = scn.nextLine().split(regex); //input from file
            Node ID1 = new Node(lineData[1], lineData[0]);
                                 //1 is child ID, 0 is parent ID
            if(lineData[0].isEmpty()) //the root
            {
                tree.addNode(ID1,  null); 
            }//end if

            tree.addNode(ID1,lineData[0]);

        }//end while    
        scn.close(); 
    }//end try
```

then in the Tree Class we have the addNode method calling the addNewChild method which is a recursive method, this is where I suspect something is going wrong:

```
   public boolean addNode(Node ID, String parentName)
{
    //When the root and parentName are both null, return true.
    //Do not throw an IllegalArgumentException for this circumstance only.
    if(parentName == null && root == null)
    {
        root = new TreeNode<Node>(ID, null);
        return true;
    }
    //When the parentName of the node being added refers to the root
    //as its parent.
    if(parentName.equals(root.Node().getName()))
    {
        TreeNode<Node> childTreeNode =
                new TreeNode<Node>(ID, root);
        root.addChild(childTreeNode);
        return true;
    }
    //if the family tree already has this TreeNode, don't do anything
    //and return false
    if(contains(ID.getName()))
    {
        return false;
    }
    //If there is no such parent, return false
    if(contains(parentName) == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //otherwise add the TreeNode and return true.
    addNewChild(root, parentName, ID);
    return true;
}
```

the recursive method addNewChild:

```
    private void addNewChild(TreeNode<Node> name,
        String parentName, Node p)
{
    //if the parent node doesn't have any children.
    if(name.getChildren() == null)
        return; //base case
    //if the parent node's name matches the parent name of the child node
    if(name.getNode().getName().equals(parentName))
    {
        name.addChild(new TreeNode<Node>(p, name));
        return; //base case  
    }
    //iterate thru parent's getChildren list
    Iterator<TreeNode<Node>> itr = name.getChildren().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        addNewChild(itr.next(), parentName, p); //recursive case
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing in my recursive design? Is there a simpler way of solving this issue? Any input on how to solve this problem would be extremely helpful.

Comment: How are `TreeNode` and `Node` implemented?

Comment: Generally, a 'TreeNode' consists of a (Node ID, and a TreeNode<E> parentNode), and has access to an ArrayList of its children nodes. The 'Node' is an object that contains a String name and String parentName. @SubOptimal

Comment: Without knowing **your** code it's hard to find the bug in it. What is the difference between `TreeNode.Node()` and `TreeNode.getNode()`? I would suggest step through your code with a debugger and compare the flow with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here wasn't with the adding of a node to the tree, but with the input file and exception handling. Amateur mistake on my part. When building the `Tree` , the `TreeNode` and `Node` objects weren't recognizing their parents because a parent in the input file would be listed as `112\s` versus in another place in the input file listed as `112` without any whitespace. This discrepancy across the input file is what lead to the malfunction in assembling the tree.